# In Cucumber, How to pass the location of the file path such that it works for both Windows and MAC

Tags: java, windows, macos, cucumber, test-runner

In Cucumber(mvn based java project) we need to specify the location of files (e.g) feature file location in the TestRunner as below

```
@CucumberOptions(features=("src\\test\\resources\\features"),
                 glue= {"com.testing.stepdefinitions"},
                 strict = true,
                 plugin= {"pretty","html:target/cucumber",
                         "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}
                 )

public class MyRunner extends BaseClass{
}
```

How to specific the file path such that it works properly in Windows and MAC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following instead of `src\\test\\resources\\features`. This will work in both windows and Mac.

```
@CucumberOptions(features=("./src/test/resources/features"),
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `feature` attribute, replace `\\` by `/` such as : `src/test/resources/features`.
It works in applications on which I use Cucumber (Windows and Unix based OS).
Note that the atrribute javadoc states  :

> Returns:
>
> the uris to the feature(s)

An [uri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) is composed of slashes, not of backslashes.

As a side note, the backslash is a windows specific way to express a path delimiter. The standard JDK classes that rely on the "path" concept such as `File` or `Path` will cope with with slashes on Linux and likewise on Windows. But the reverse is not true.

Comment: No ,  it actually worked when i put a "." in front of it like ./src/test/resources/features instead of just src/test/resources/features as a common path for both MAC and windows

Comment: That is very interesting. I don't have the issue with Ubuntu.